# MySQL: How can I find duplicate records in table, and update another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with folowing structure

**tbl_inv**

```
SKU   VID  UPC
AAA    2   0123
AA2    3   0123
AA3    4   0123
BBB    2   1234
```

This table include all products, with sku, vid and UPC number.

**tbl_images**

```
SKU   VID  IMAGE_HASHNAME
AAA    2   fcd20a60fd5c1b64cee40ac0c019a022
```

THIS table includes product with images. 
I want to make update and inserted images on this products without image and UPC code are match.

Product with sku AAA, AA2 and AA3 are matched, because UPC numbers are duplicated.

The final result, which must be obtained is:

AA2 assigned value on AAA for IMAGE_HASHNAME
AA3 assigned value on AAA for IMAGE_HASHNAME

This new recort must inserted in tbl_images

**tbl_images after update**

```
SKU   VID  IMAGE_HASHNAME
AAA    2   fcd20a60fd5c1b64cee40ac0c019a022
AA2    3   fcd20a60fd5c1b64cee40ac0c019a022
AA3    4   fcd20a60fd5c1b64cee40ac0c019a022




SELECT i.UPC as upc
        FROM tbl_inv i 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_images img ON img.sku = i.sku AND img.vid = i.vid
        WHERE i.UPC != '' 
        AND img.image_hashname IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY i.upc
        having count(i.upc) > 1
```

With this query I trying to find matched records in table, but not show records.
After this query I want to copy file with PHP, and insert VALUES in table tbl_images.
Where I wrong ?

I apologize for my English .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find the matches

```
SELECT upc FROM tbl_inv
WHERE sku in ( SELECT sku FROM tbl_images)
```

this query will return the 0123 which is upc of SKU  AAA

-here assumption made as sku is unique

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select t3.SKU,t3.VID,t4.IMAGE_HASHNAME 
from tbl_inv as t3 left join 
   (selectt1.SKU,t1.VID,t1.UPC,t2.IMAGE_HASHNAME 
          from tbl_inv as t1 right join tbl_images ON t1.SKU=t2.SKU)
             as t4 on t3.UPC=t4.UPC
```